# Accessing DAG configuration variable in its constructor

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

In Airflow 2.0, when creating a DAG using the DAG constructor - I would like to use one of its trigger configuration parameters for naming its dag_id.
For example, as I use the Google Cloud Composer environment, I have something like the following code snippets:

**trigger_dag.sh**

```
DAG_VERSION=some_dag_v1.0.0
TRIGGER_PARAMS='{"dag_version":"'"${DAG_VERSION}"'"}';
gcloud beta composer environments run "${AIRFLOW_ENV_NAME}" --location=us-central1 dags trigger -- "${DAG_VERSION}" --conf "${TRIGGER_PARAMS}";
```

**dag.py**

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id=conf.dag_version, ## <- How do I access DAG config variables here?
    schedule_interval=conf.dag_schedule_interval)
```

If I were inside a Python operator, I would have probably defined `conf = context['dag_run'].conf` , where **context is given as an argument. However, I'm not sure that it's possible to do it that way when initially defining the DAG in the top level of dag.py.

Comment: I'm confused. `dags trigger` is a command to execute a DAG. You can not execute a DAG if it doesn't exist first. If you are looking to construct a DAG dynamically it means you need a factory method to create it.

Comment: The DAG and its relevant files exist, but in my example - the "DAG_VERSION" parameter is defined in an external source and I would like it to be included in the dag_id field (mainly for debugging purposes).
My workaround for it is to use an internal configuration file that is included in the DAG files. However, it is redundant as it duplicates the external definition.

Comment: OK, it seems like my bad - I confused the functionality of ```dags trigger``` as I thought that it also creates the DAG using dag.py object constructor, and not only executes it. If it were like that, I wouldn't have to pass ```-- "${DAG_VERSION}"```.
It means, that in any case, the definition of dag_id should be internal.

Comment: Great so if you can edit your question and clarify what exactly are you asking now